# python name not defined even though it is

Tags: python, nameerror

I know this is basic but i actually don't even know what I've done wrong.

```
while True:
    try:
        end=int(input("If You Dont Want To Buy Anything Press 1 To Exit\nOr If You Would Like To Try Again Please Press 2"))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nPlease Enter Only 1 Or 2")
    if end==1:
        exit()
    elif end==2:
        continue
```

I have literally defined end at the start and yet the error is `NameError: name 'end' is not defined` I've even tried making end a global.

Comment: `end` is only assigned to if there was no `ValueError`. If `int()` raises an exception, then the assignment *never takes place*.

Comment: Following @MartijnPieters comment, read https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions to understand the proper way of using exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`end` is only assigned to if there was no `ValueError`. If `int()` raises an exception, then the assignment *never takes place*.

Either test for valid `end` values **inside** the `try` (so that you know no exception was raised), or assign a default value to `end` first.

For example, the following will not throw your exception and still prompt the user to re-enter the number if anything other than `1` or `2` was entered:

```
while True:
    try:
        end=int(input("If You Dont Want To Buy Anything Press 1 To Exit\nOr If You Would Like To Try Again Please Press 2"))
        if end==1:
            exit()
        elif end==2:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print("\nPlease Enter Only 1 Or 2")
```

Note that I moved the `print()` to be *outside* the `except` block; it'll be printed if an exception was thrown or when no `break` or `exit()` was executed. Note that I used `break` here instead of `continue` to exit the `while True` loop; `continue` would just start the next iteration, prompting the user to enter a number again.

Comment: thanks I guess I was being stupid in the end... Is this why if i entered a number first then a letter there was no error?

Comment: @E_J: exactly, because `end` still was assigned that number.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained the problem; here's a canonical solution.  This matches the way many of us regard the process:
 - grab a response
 - until I get a *legal* response
 - ... tell the user what's wrong
 - ... get a new response

```
input_prompt = "If You Don't Want To Buy Anything Press 1 To Exit\nOr If You Would Like To Try Again Please Press 2"
response = input(input_prompt)
while response != '1' and response != '2':
    print("\nPlease Enter Only 1 Or 2")
    response = input(input_prompt)
end = int(reponse)
```

This has no unnatural loop exits (harder to follow and maintain), and no exception processing (slow).

Answer (score 0):

It tries to assign a value to end, but catches a ValueError and after the except it tries to see what 'end' is however it was never assigned a value due to the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If `int(input(...))` fails, a `ValueError` is raised. That happens before `end` is assigned. Add another control statement in the error handling, for instance

```
while True:
    try:
        end=int(input("If You Dont Want To Buy Anything Press 1 To Exit\nOr If You Would Like To Try Again Please Press 2"))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nPlease Enter Only 1 Or 2")
        continue  # ask again
    if end==1:
        exit()
    elif end==2:
        continue
```